# k8s access images from behind a firewall

Tags: kubernetes, http-proxy

I'm trying to run a k8s cluster from behind a http proxy.  I am able to download images from the corresponding repositories, however when I try to provision the same using k8s I get `errImagePull`  For example if I try

```
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.5.0/all-in-one.yaml
```

Then I get the following error on the pod

```
 Normal   Pulling    37m (x4 over 38m)      kubelet            Pulling image "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.5.0"
  Warning  Failed     37m (x4 over 38m)      kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.5.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.5.0": failed to resolve reference "docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.5.0": failed to do request: Head https://docker.elastic.co/v2/eck/eck-operator/manifests/1.5.0: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp [::1]:3128: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Failed     37m (x4 over 38m)      kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

Now when I directly try `docker image pull docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:1.5.0` directly on the box it works fine.  I think I need to setup a http proxy for k8s, but not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions are welcome.  I'm using `kind` on my linux instance and `cntlm` is configured as well, hence my usage of localhost:3128 as proxy.

I also tried this using minikube with the following command

```
minikube start --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 --docker-env no_proxy=localhost
```

I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `localhost` is the `host` on which Docker is running to support `minikube` or `kind` based `Kubernetes` nodes, you need to use `host.docker.internal:3128` as the proxy, instead of `localhost:3128`. This [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264) is relevant.

For `minikube`, `host.minikube.internal:3128` would also work. More information [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/).

Comment: thanks for this, I tried the above command with `host.docker.interal:3128` and `host.minikube.internal:3128`, both of them didn't work, I still get the same error.

Comment: @tmpdev are you able to make progress?

Comment: nope, no progress I'm still stuck, I added some additional information to the chat.

Comment: I hope you are adding host.minikube.internal to no_proxy along with the CIDR for internal docker network

Comment: thanks a lot GSSwain for your help on this, I feel I have some weird version of docker and its messing up the whole thing, furthermore I don't think I will spend more time on this since I have more pressing development tasks. Thanks again for you help